# How did the Four Horsemen do the teleportation trick during the first act?

Tags: plot-explanation, now-you-see-me

We know how the Four Horsemen robbed the bank in *Now You See Me*, and we know the French guy was preselected for the trick.

But how did they convince everyone (the French guy included) that he was actually in a safe in Paris?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually explained by Thaddeus Bradley when he examines the trick with the FBI afterwards. The French guy (who was preselected because of the exact bank they needed) was not teleported. Instead, the "teleportation device" he was placed in just **threw him right under the stage, where the Horsemen built an exact replica of the bank safe's interior**.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

> **Thaddeus:** I personally prefer to take the stairs to Paris. Welcome to the City of Light, Agent Rhodes.
>
> **Rhodes:** So they got a vault set...And it's the exact replica
>   of the little French guy's bank...
>
> **Thaddeus:** He was a dupe, not a plant. They chose him. They knew which seat he was in...He was selected. They programmed his mind to make him go to Las Vegas. And then they kept reinforcing it, until he did. They trailed him. They studied him. Nothing was left to chance. He had no idea he was their target. And they simply activated him in Vegas.

So he just walked around under the stage the whole time, thinking he was in the actual bank safe. And as you already explained yourself, the real bank was robbed much earlier (or actually not really robbed, but the money just exchanged beforehand).

Comment: also he was hypnotised

Comment: @madmada Hmm, but I'm not sure that was part of the safe illusion, since that should already work without him being hypnotized.

Comment: May be, but as I see it Rhodes spotted the "hatch" getting closed after him and immediately realizes that he fell into a room under the stage because that's easy to guess for a lucid mind while the French guy didn't realize any of that because he was in some sort of a trance

Comment: @madmada Hmm, granted.